# Angular remove first Image

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an input to select multiple images. When selecting the various images they are placed in boxes (1 large box and the rest small).

I can delete the images in the small boxes, but I can't delete the one from the 1st box (big box).

Does anyone help me get the big box image remove working? Is it possible that by deleting the big box image, one of the small box images will fill that box?

Another thing that is not right is that to load the image in the first box I use src = url [0], it is always loading an image, even if it does not exist, how can I solve it?

Thanks !!!

[My Code --> StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyuwtq)

**Html**

```
<div class="drop">
      <div class="cont">
        <div class="browse">
            Upload files
          </div>
        <div class="desc">
          Click to upload or drop your files
        </div>       
      </div>
      <img [src]="urls[0]"><span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(url)">X</span>
      <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
</div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let url of urls | slice:1">
          <img [src]="url"><span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(url)">X</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
files:any;
  urls = new Array<string>();
  detectFiles(event) {
    this.urls = [];
    this.files = event.target.files;   
      for (let file of this.files) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.urls.push(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
  }
  private deleteImage(url: any): void {
    this.urls = this.urls.filter((a) => a !== url);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you are passing  `url` to the `deleteImage()` function instead of `url[0]`.

```
<img [src]="urls[0]">
<span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(url[0])">X</span>
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgyfam

---

#### Edit (response to the comment)

You can wrap the `<img [src]="urls[0]">` in an `<ng-container>` conditionally showing if `urls.length > 0`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="urls.length > 0">
  <img [src]="urls[0]">
  <span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(urls[0])">X</span>
</ng-container>
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvn93z

Comment: Perfect thank you!!
Do you know how I can solve the problem of always trying to load an image into src [0] even if I don't have any images selected? this should only happen when selecting an image ... I tried * ngif but got no results :(

Comment: @HarryJames Check my edit, I think that is what you're looking for.